# What is the difference between onclick and href for anchor tag?

Tags: javascript

What is the difference from the `<a onclick="window.location.href = 'example.com'">Example.com</a>` to `<a href="example.com">Example.com</a>` ?

Comment: Don't ever use the `onclick` version. It's a nightmare for people who like to be able to open links in new tabs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The one requires JavaScript to be enabled to call the code. This would break search engines from following the links. The other is a standard HTML feature, not requiring any javascript.